# Count size of set iterated by XSLT for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am writing a XSLT stylesheet that generates another XSLT stylesheet.

In one part of the code, I am iterating / grouping elements:

```
<xsl:for-each-group
    select="descendant::FormSectionElements[not(LoadBindBase = '')]" 
    group-by="concat(LoadBindBase,SubmitBindBase)">

     ...

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

In another area in the template, which is nested at a different level, I need to obtain the number of items which would have been iterated by the above loop.

Is there an XPath expression that can count the size of the set that would be iterated by for-each-group?  In this other area of the template, I am able to obtain the same elements as in the select attribute of the for-each-group.

Answer (score 4):

> an XPath expression that can count the size of the set that
>   would be iterated by for-each-group?

```
count(current-group())
```

will return the size of the current group and:

```
last()
```

will return the number of groups.

Comment: In one area of the template, I am iterating the the loop and calling other templates, but I can't find a way to save the count in a variable.  In a separate area, I am not iterating the loop, but just want the size iterated by it - do i need to iterate the loop again to obtain the count?  Or, is there an expression that would compute the same count?

Comment: "*I can't find a way to save the count in a variable.*" Why not? `<xsl:variable name="count-groups" select="last()" />` should work just fine. I'm afraid I cannot comment on the rest because I don't see your code and have no idea what you're doing. But as long as you are within the `xsl:for-each-group`, the variable will be in-scope and accessible. If you leave this scope, you will need to pass the value along as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::FormSectionElements[not(LoadBindBase = '')])" />
```