# Is order of iteration by xsl for-each-group consistent?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Is the order of iteration in for-each-group predictable with the same data? or could it change if the same loop is executed twice, for example I have this loop repeated twice in separate parts of a template:

```
<xsl:for-each-group
            select="descendant::FormSectionElements[not(LoadBindBase = '')]" 
            group-by="LoadBindBase">

... first ...

</xsl:for-each-group>


<xsl:for-each-group
            select="descendant::FormSectionElements[not(LoadBindBase = '')]" 
            group-by="LoadBindBase">

... second ...

</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default order for processing groups is "order of first appearance": if the first appearance of "London" as a grouping key precedes the first appearance of "Paris", then the group with key "London" is processed before the group with key "Paris". You can change the order using an xsl:sort as a child of xsl:for-each-group. In both cases the order is not only stable between multiple uses of the instruction, but predictable and interoperable between different implementations.

I'm not sure I would agree with @michael.hor257k that it's a bad idea to do the same grouping twice. Firstly, until you move to XSLT 3.0 with maps, there's no convenient data structure for holding the groups. Secondly, there's a memory-time trade-off here so it depends on your circumstances.

The way to do this with maps in 3.0 would be:

```
<xsl:variable name="groups" as="map(xs:string, node()*)">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:for-each-group
         select="descendant::FormSectionElements[not(LoadBindBase = '')]">
      <xsl:map-entry key="current-grouping-key()" select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:map>
</xsl:variable>
```

and then you can iterate over the groups using, for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="map:keys($groups)">
  <group key="{.}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$groups(.)" mode="xxx"/>
  </group>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The order of processing of map:keys() is unpredictable -- but it should be consistent across multiple calls.

Answer (score 1):

1. The ordering among groups is defined in the XSLT 2.0 specification, and will be the same every time you call the `xsl:for-each-group` instruction with the same population (unless you change it explicitly using `xsl:sort`).
2. The grouping operation can be expensive, and you would be well advised to perform it only once. If necessary, you can place the entire result of the grouping (or only some characteristics of it, as [discussed in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355694/count-size-of-set-iterated-by-xslt-for-each-group#comment66041997_39355810)) in a variable for later reuse.

---

P.S. See: http://xyproblem.info/